# list all existing user in a txt file [Linux]

Tags: linux, debian, terminal

i am trying to make a txt file with a list of existing user in Linux debian10, all i want in the list is username of each existing user, can anyone teach me how to do it?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

This will print the first field of `/etc/passwd`, which contains all the accounts on a system.

```bsh
awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

To save that output to a file, use the `>` file redirection operator, e.g.

```bsh
awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd > users.txt
```

Comment: Thanks alot and is there a way i could extract only the username of those users?

Answer (score 0):

To list the normal users on debian:

```
getent passwd {1000..6000}
```

1000 is the minimum UID :

```
grep ^UID_MIN /etc/login.defs
```

6000 is the maximum UID :

```
grep ^UID_MAX /etc/login.defs
```

see [man login.def](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/login/login.defs.5.en.html)